# Не подключается к Wi-Fi Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Установил линукс минт. Пробую подключится к корпоративной сети, не получается. Нюанс в том, что сеть не простая, а с авторизацией по логину и паролю. В графическом интерфейсе при клике на сеть, начинает крутится кружок, но потом пропадает без каких либо объявлений.
К сетям без пароля и к стандартным wpa2 подключается без вопросов

Как решить проблему?

Какие протоколы использует сеть, ее конфигурацию итд не знаю

Comment: как всегда - вначале смотрите логи (dmesg). Там очень часто бывают полезные штуки

Comment: @KoVadim Примерно вот эти логи нужны? (это другая сеть и логи обрезаны из-за ограничения по символам) [ 6855.005553] wlp3s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[ 6855.038616] wlp3s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[ 6855.039411] wlp3s0: authenticated
[ 6855.044893] wlp3s0: associated
[ 6855.045006] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x11111
[ 6855.045007] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country
[ 6855.045009] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3
[ 6855.045009] ath: Country alpha2 being used: RU

Comment: Да, где то они. Вот такое бывает (у меня было), если сеть запомнило, а потом настройки сети поменялись. Лечилось поиском нужных файлов с конфигом и удалением

Comment: @KoVadim [   68.829277] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
[   68.829292] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e5(Transmitter ID)
[   68.829301] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[   68.829308] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout  
[   70.850626] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5

Comment: @KoVadim [  109.295369] Could not find key with description: [496013e6dab8f97b]
[  109.295373] process_request_key_err: No key
[  109.295374] Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [496013e6dab8f97b]
[  109.295375] One or more global auth toks could not properly register; rc = [-2]
[  109.295376] Error parsing options; rc = [-2]